# How to find cause and of the SocketException with message that an established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcpclient

I know the similar question may have been asked many times, but I want to represent the behavior I'm seeing and find if somebody can help predict the cause of this.

I am writing a windows service which connects to other windows service over TCP.
There are 100 user entities of this, and 5 connections per each. These users perform their tasks using their individual connections.

The application goes on withough seeing this problem for 1 or 2 days. Or sometimes show the problem right after starting (-rarely). The best run I had was like 4 to 5 days without showing this exception. And after that application died or I had to stop it for various reasons.

I want to know what can be causing this? 
Here is the stacktrace.

`System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartWriting(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)`

Comment: @cdpnet: Is this on an internal network protected from outside malicious intent? I haven't personally experienced this *yet*, but my first guess is that an attempt was made to connect to your socket that shouldn't be.

Comment: This is on an internal network of the company, running on our desktops.

Comment: some actual code would be nice. are you creating socket connections programmatically via custom code? I've been there

Answer (score 3):

Did you find a solution to this? Perhaps you can come closer to a solution if you add network tracing to your app.config?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="Sockets"/>
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
        <switches>
            <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="31"/>
        </switches>
        <sharedListeners>
            <add name="Sockets" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\socketdump.log"/>
        </sharedListeners>
        <trace autoflush="true"/>
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Also, perhaps you could setup logging for TLS/SSL. Add the following DWORD and set it to 7, to your registry, reboot and watch all schannel events in the System Event Log:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\EventLogging
```

Hope that help, but it might be lots of punches in the dark I guess...

Comment: More details should be extracted from System.NET tracing, if you happen to read Microsoft KB http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947285, which provides an example.